# Document preview in a new tab without downloading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Working on a project, I need to make documents that are attached to a field available for preview. So far, I have come up with this code.

```
$scope.onPreview = function(attachmentId) {
  console.info("onPreview: attachment id #" + attachmentId);
  $window.open('/api/v3/attachments/' + attachmentId,'_blank');
};

...

<a ng-href=""
         class="secondary-action glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"
         tooltip-placement="bottom"
         tooltip="preview"
         ng-click="onPreview(attachment.id)">
</a>
```

This does open a new tab, but does NOT display the content of the document, as I expected it... Could it be because of the API I am using?
I also tried this.

```
$scope.onPreview = function(attachmentId) {
  console.info("onPreview: attachment id #" + attachmentId);
  var atchmt = $http.get('/api/v3/attachments/' + attachmentId);
  $window.open(atchmt,'_blank');
};
```

This time I got an other type of error.

> Bad Request : bad URI '/ma/[object%20Object]'

Does anybody have an idea what I can try? And because this will not only be used on my computer but on many computers that I don't have access to, I can not install a browser plugin to enable this action...

Comment: you should mention a mimeType of that file while sending as response from server side

Comment: can't pass a `$http` promise to window.open. What's in the request response?

Comment: Adding `console.info(atchmt);` I get `[object Object]`

Comment: try console.info(JSON.stringify(atchmt))